# Replace <Keyword> with a different string from a list

Tags: microsoft-word

So i have a letter like this

> HI <-User->
>
> This is someone and thank you for reading

And got a list of users

> Jhon
>   Rick
>   Madona

How do i print, or save a document with each one of the list, replacing once the <-User-> keyword?

So i can get

> HI Jhon
>
> This is someone and thank you for reading

-

> HI Rick
>
> This is someone and thank you for reading

-

> HI Madona
>
> This is someone and thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a "mail merge" or merge. It is under the "mailings" tab in my version of word. You make a data file, associate that data file with the document you want, then start placing field markers for word to replace with data from the data file.

See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx